# Wrapping text in tabulator spreadsheet

Tags: tabulator

I'm using the tabulator package to try to turn a Google Spreadsheet into a readable/ filterable/ searchable table for a website.

The spreadsheet we are trying to format has fields with a large amount of text (some paragraphs and some bullet-points).

The tabulator package by default does not wrap text within each cell. The entire paragraph of text appears as a single line which runs on horizontally.

Is there a way to limit the width of the table, and to wrap text within each cell?

Comment: See http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/format Looks like the textarea formatter should do this? If not, there is a custom formatter you might be able to develop. Without a [mcve] it's hard to answer with context.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the ***textarea*** formatter on a column if you want the text to wrap in the cell

in the column definition for the cell

```
{title:"Long Text Column", field:"longtext", formatter:"textarea"},
```

The [Formatting Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/format#format-builtin) includes descriptions and examples of all the built-in formatters.

There are numerous ways to layout the columns, to either fit the data they contain or fit the table. the [Layout Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/layout) includes detailed explanations and examples of the ways to layout the table.

If you are looking to set the width in px on a specific column, this can be done using the width property in the column definition:

```
{title:"Long Text Column", field:"longtext", formatter:"textarea", width:100},
```

Comment: I now understand how to use formatter:"textarea" to cause text to wrap. However, I should have mentioned that I'm also using responsiveLayoutCollapseFormatter to turn hidden columns into expandable list form. 

How do I cause the text to wrap in this expandable list format? Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing it's a typo, but `field:"textarea"` should probably be replaced with `formatter:"textarea"` in both places.